# Understanding the Definition of the Tensor Product of Chain Complexes

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

The tensor product of chain complexes (of $R$ modules) $C_\bullet ,D_\bullet$ is defined as
$$(C_\bullet \otimes D_\bullet )_n = \bigoplus_{i+j=n} C_i \otimes_R  D_{j}$$

I understand this definition works by yielding a chain complex (with a nilpotent boundary operator as usually defined), but I don't understand anything about it beyond that.

**Questions:**

1. What is the motivation behind this definition?
2. Is there any geometric insight to be gained here?
3. Where can I read about its history?

---

**Added:** Does the tensor product of chain complexes as defined above posses some universal property (which is easy to formulate) in $\mathsf {Ch}_\bullet$?

Comment: check Jean Dieudonné's *"A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology 1900-1960"*.

Comment: @janmarqz I looked (around page 92), but the definition is just given there :(

Comment: If you're computing (co)homology of topological spaces, tensor product of complexes corresponds to the usual product of spaces.

Comment: @Exterior: did you see around that it is used for the Künneth formula?

Comment: @janmarqz I'm only vaguely familiar with the statement of Kunneth's formula on wiki, so I didn't understand anything Dieudonne writes about it there.

Comment: @GrigoryM sorry for being dense, but could you please formulate this correspondence?

Comment: @Exterior: have patience and endurance, you already reached in here

Comment: @Exterior Details depend on the version of (co)homology you're using — but if, say, $X$ and $Y$ are CW-spaces then $C(X\times Y)\cong C(X)\otimes C(Y)$ where $C(-)$ is the cellular chain complex.

Comment: @GrigoryM, this is a version of the Kunneth formula, right? If aiming for this (generally quasi-) isomorphism should be my motivation, I'd like to see how the above definition for the tensor product would hint at it.

Comment: @Exterior For cellular homology this is [not some complicated quasiisomorphism but] an almost tautological isomorphism: on the level of elements that's just $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m=\mathbb R^{n+m}$ — and for the differential that's exactly what motivates the definition of the differential in $C\otimes D$. As for the Kunneth formula, aforementioned lemma allows one apply Kunneth formuma from homological algebra (computing $H(C\otimes D)$ in terms of $H(C)$ and $H(D)$) to compute $H(X\times Y)$.

Comment: ...details can be found in most algebraic topology textbook (e.g. in Hatcher's). And IMHO it's very useful in general to study (some) algebraic topology in parallel with homological algebra.

Comment: @GrigoryM, thank you, I'll try to learn more algebraic topology.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual universal property of a tensor product?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft making bilinear maps linear, yup.

Comment: Here's one useful ness of tensor product of chain complexes from a  more of a Commutative Algebra view point: Let $M,N$ be modules over a Commutative ring $R$ and let $P_{\bullet}\to M\to 0 $ and $Q_{\bullet}\to N\to 0 $ be any projective resolutions of $M,N$ respectively. Then $H_i(P_{\bullet} \otimes_R Q_{\bullet})\cong \text{Tor}_i^R(M,N), \forall i$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $(C,d_C)$ and $(D, d_D)$ be two chain complexes of $R$-modules, where $d_C$ and $d_D$ are differentials of degree $+1$. By definition, each $C_i$ and $D_j$ are $R$-modules. We want to "compose" the above complexes in a tensorial way; the definition you propose has 2 main effects:

1. each $(C\otimes_R D)_n$ is again an $R$-module.
2. the induced differential (which is probably the missing part in the OP) $$d_{C\otimes_R D}:=d_C\otimes_R 1_D + 1_C\otimes_R d_D,$$

is compatible with the (co)homological grading. In fact, for all $c\in C_i$ and $g\in D_j$, s.t. $i+j = n$, i.e. $c\otimes_R g\in (C\otimes_R D)_{n}$ then

$$d_{C\otimes_R D}(c\otimes_R g)= d_C c\otimes_R g + (-1)^i c \otimes_R d_Dg\in (C\otimes_R D)_{n+1}, $$

as $d_C c\in C_{i+1}$ and $d_D g\in D_{j+1}$. We used the Koszul sign rule.

For topological / geometric insights I refer to the text "Rational Homotopy Theory" by Felix, Halperin and Thomas. For formal definitions and applications in homological algebra the book by Gelfand and Manin is recommended, instead.

Comment: I don't know what the Koszul sign rule is, and a quick google search yielded only [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364904/tensor-algebra-of-dg-algebra) extremely brief sketch of the idea.

Comment: The Koszul sign rule justifies the sign $(-1)^i$ in the formula of the differential for the tensor complex above; it is not so relevant at this stage. The link you refer to explains the rule quite well: it can be summarized in ""exchanging two symbols you multiply the result by the sign (−1), raised to the power of the products of their degrees".

Comment: It's frustrating to just accept that though. Can you direct me to more detailed explanations?

Comment: Uhm, ok: try to compute $d_{C\otimes_R D}^2(c\otimes_R d)$ without extra $(-1)^{...}$ sign in front of $c\otimes d_D d$: do you get $d_{C\otimes_R D}^2(c\otimes d)= 0$, as wished? Answer: no. This implies that $C\otimes_R D$ is not a chain complex. The Koszul sign rule guarantees $d_{C\otimes_R D}^2(c\otimes d)= 0$, instead.

Comment: Using $d$ for differential and for element of $D$ is very confusing. Could you alter your notation in your answer?

Comment: @tom ok, no problem: I edit my answer

Comment: for explanation of Koszul sign rule, read this: http://www.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/papers/signs.pdf

Comment: @Exterior did the answer help? Do you need more details?

Comment: @Avitus certainly! I upvoted it, but I refrained from accepting in hope for some more answers. I still don't feel at ease with the "convolution" between different gradings. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find additional intuition anywhere..

Comment: If you are familiar with alg. topology, I'd suggest to have a look at the first example in http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+chain+complexes for a geometric exposition

Answer (score 0):

$\{Ci\otimes Dj\}$ is nice double complex，with left hand side is $n$-th object in total complex of the double complex. you can refer to balancing ext and tor in Weibel's book. it has a nice application to prove two left derived functor of $A\otimes B$ gives same functor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have never seen definition of tensor product of chain complexes before but it seams to me quite sensible. I did a very crude drawing which might give you some motivation behind the definition (If I got it right :D)

In the picture we have two chain complexes $C_\bullet,D_\bullet$, in fact they are simplicial complexes of dimension $1$. They are both just an edge with two end vertices. Now you would like to somehow combine them and get square and that is the tensor product. Or you could take two circles and get torus or circle and edge and get cylinder.

I did not label every element of $C_\bullet \otimes D_\bullet$ I just labeled vertex $a\otimes d$, edge $e\otimes c$ and face $e\otimes f$.

[image]

Comment: I would love an explanation of the image :)

Comment: Is that enough?

Comment: I don't follow. Why are chain complexes simplicial complexes? What does the definition I gave have to do with this?

Comment: This is just simple example of tensor product between two very simple simplicial complexes.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand what this square has to do with tensor products in particular.. It could just as easily be a representation of a homotopy, no? Why does your illustration match the definition above?